# RabbitMQ closed connection on method CreateModel()

Tags: c#, windows, exception, rabbitmq

I'm trying to run Producer example from tutorials, but RabbitMQ closed connection with exception:

*Exception thrown: 'RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException' in RabbitMQ.Client.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException' occurred in RabbitMQ.Client.dll
The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Library, code=541, text='Unexpected Exception', classId=0, methodId=0, cause=System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.*

Code is:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
var channel = connection.CreateModel(); // <-- crash is here on this line
```

**Notes:**

1. RabbitMQ started and working - is easy to send/get message manually via RabbitMQ Management web-UI.
2. Status or RabbitMQ received by command **rabbitmq-diagnostics.bat status** is ok, no one problem.
3. exe-file added to Windows-firewall for avoid any blocking
4. From the Wireshark we can see that RabbitMQ accepts connection and after some actions - sends Reset:

[image: Text]

**From the RabbitMQ logs:**

```
2023-05-17 19:49:59.763000+03:00 [info] <0.930.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.930.0> ([::1]:49412 -> [::1]:5672)
2023-05-17 19:49:59.779000+03:00 [info] <0.930.0> connection <0.930.0> ([::1]:49412 -> [::1]:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>   crasher:
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>     initial call: rabbit_reader:init/3
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>     pid: <0.930.0>
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>     registered_name: []
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>     exception exit: {unexpected_message,{'EXIT',#Port<0.229>,einval}}
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>       in function  rabbit_reader:handle_other/2 (rabbit_reader.erl, line 644)
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>       in call from rabbit_reader:mainloop/4 (rabbit_reader.erl, line 535)
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>       in call from rabbit_reader:run/1 (rabbit_reader.erl, line 457)
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>       in call from rabbit_reader:start_connection/5 (rabbit_reader.erl, line 356)
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>     ancestors: [<0.928.0>,<0.603.0>,<0.602.0>,<0.601.0>,<0.599.0>,<0.598.0>,
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                   rabbit_sup,<0.233.0>]
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>     message_queue_len: 0
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>     messages: []
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>     links: [<0.928.0>]
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>     dictionary: [{{ch_pid,<0.939.0>},{1,#Ref<0.2052854348.121110529.34620>}},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                   {client_properties,
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                       [{<<"product">>,longstr,<<"RabbitMQ">>},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                        {<<"version">>,longstr,
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                         <<"6.5.0+4c91cae8ae5eb0194e02a83f1b0cedfe29ad8312">>},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                        {<<"platform">>,longstr,<<".NET">>},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                        {<<"copyright">>,longstr,
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                         <<"Copyright (c) 2007-2020 VMware, Inc.">>},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                        {<<"information">>,longstr,
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                         <<"Licensed under the MPL. See https://www.rabbitmq.com/">>},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                        {<<"capabilities">>,table,
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                         [{<<"publisher_confirms">>,bool,true},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                          {<<"exchange_exchange_bindings">>,bool,true},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                          {<<"basic.nack">>,bool,true},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                          {<<"consumer_cancel_notify">>,bool,true},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                          {<<"connection.blocked">>,bool,true},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                          {<<"authentication_failure_close">>,bool,true}]},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                        {<<"connection_name">>,void,undefined}]},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                   {process_name,
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                       {rabbit_reader,<<"[::1]:49412 -> [::1]:5672">>}},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                   {{channel,1},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>                    {<0.939.0>,{method,rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1}}}]
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>     trap_exit: true
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>     status: running
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>     heap_size: 1598
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>     stack_size: 28
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>     reductions: 9624
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0>   neighbours:
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.930.0> 
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>     supervisor: {<0.928.0>,rabbit_connection_sup}
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>     errorContext: child_terminated
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>     reason: {unexpected_message,{'EXIT',#Port<0.229>,einval}}
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>     offender: [{pid,<0.930.0>},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>                {id,reader},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>                {mfargs,{rabbit_reader,start_link,
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>                                       [<0.929.0>,
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>                                        {acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5672}]}},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>                {restart_type,intrinsic},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>                {shutdown,300000},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>                {child_type,worker}]
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>     supervisor: {<0.928.0>,rabbit_connection_sup}
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>     errorContext: shutdown
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>     reason: reached_max_restart_intensity
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>     offender: [{pid,<0.930.0>},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>                {id,reader},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>                {mfargs,{rabbit_reader,start_link,
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>                                       [<0.929.0>,
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>                                        {acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5672}]}},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>                {restart_type,intrinsic},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>                {shutdown,300000},
2023-05-17 19:50:00.784000+03:00 [error] <0.928.0>                {child_type,worker}]
```

**QUESTION:** how to fix this issue?

Comment: are they talking the same protocol? amqp or amqps? 0-9-1 or 0-10?

Comment: @IvanRubinson: as I see - AMQP. 
Full screenshot is here: https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/Zona8zgtFC8z.png

Comment: And output of status command is here: https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/4IwOuniU6Hy8.png

Comment: Can you give more details? RabbitMQ version? Erlang versions ?

Comment: @GabrieleSantomaggio :

2023-05-18 12:29:31.670000+03:00 [info] <0.233.0>  Starting RabbitMQ 3.11.16 on Erlang 26.0 [jit]

Comment: You are using erlang 26 with 3.11.16, which is not compatible.  
You can: Use the 3.12 version  (compatible with erlang 26. )  or install erlang 25.x

Comment: @GabrieleSantomaggio how do you know the versions are not compatible? Is there a ref in some document?

Comment: @GabrieleSantomaggio : thanks, now is working.

One note: First I've deleted both - Erlang and RabbitMQ.

After: I downloaded Erlang 25.3.2 and installed, also installed the same RabbitMQ 3.11.16 (because 3.12 is pre-release).

Comment: @IvanRubinson I work for the RabbitMQ team. Erlang 26 is not fully supported yet. We are still doing internal tests.  See https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html the best way is still use erlang 25. Erlang 26 will be officially supported in some 3.12.x version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For future readers.

The problem here is that you are using Erlang 26 with RabbitMQ 3.11.x.
You have to use Erlang 25.
See https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html

Erlang 26 is not officially supported yet, we are working on it; at some point in 3.12.x will be supported.

Answer (score 0):

in windows, unistall Erlang 26 is not easy - you need to unistall , and then delete all files in

C:\Program Files\Erlang OTP\erts-14.1

or else the next time you install
RabbitMQ it will bound to this version

in regedit see that value of

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ericsson\Erlang\ErlSrv\1.1\RabbitMQ\
Machine
```

is

```
C:\Program Files\Erlang OTP\erts-13.0.4\bin\erl.exe
```

and not erts-14.1